# How to push data onto BehaviourSubject in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my Ionic / Angular app, I am trying to retrieve data from firestore using the below code:

```
private _users = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

return of(
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").get()
        .then((docs) => {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                this._users.push(doc);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
    })
);
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to compile:

```
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<User[]>'.
```

Can someone please tell me how I can retrieve data from this collection & populate `_users` with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your collection thought dedicated `BehaviorSubject` property called `value`:

```
docs.forEach((doc) => {
   this._users.next([...this._users.value, doc]);
});
```

But it looks like you can simply update the whole array:

```
.then((docs) => {
  this._users.next(docs);
})
```

Also, don't forget to convert `DocumentData` to `User` object, e.g.:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

.then((docs) => {
  this._users.next(docs.map(doc => {
    const data = doc.data() as User;
    return { id: doc.id, name: data.name };
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I replace the `forEach` with your code, I get this error: _Argument of type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]'.
  Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use push with observables, you can fix it by

```
 this._users.next(doc);
```